# Problem reading 1st non-commented line just after using dropwhile function to skip commented lines

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to read several .dat files and extract appropriate information from them.

The .dat files usually start with about 15-25 lines of comments (line starts with a “#”), then the next two lines are numbers which indicate their nature and size. However, once I try to read the first non-commented line, my code seems to start reading from the second non-commented line. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is :/ Any help would be much appreciated since this is preventing me from doing other more complex operations with those .dat files.

Here is my flawed code:

PS: If there's a more pythonic way, please let me know :)

```
#Packages needed
from itertools import dropwhile

# In[]
#defining function to check if line starts with some character, here #
def is_comment(s):
    # return true if a line starts with #
    return s.startswith('#')

# In[]
file = "foo.dat"   

#viewing important info
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in dropwhile(is_comment, f):           

        Nat = f.readline()
        print("Nature:", Nat)

        S = f.readline()
        print("Size, S:", S)

        break
```

Please find attached a screenshot of the foo.dat file in question.
[foo.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9BLd.png)
Or text version here: https://pastebin.com/C91dpUXK
*Edit: added link to text file

Comment: Please add the dat file to the question as text and not as an image

Comment: don't mix f.readline with for loop on the lines, iterate on the file manually

Comment: Does this work: https://pastebin.com/C91dpUXK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's expected

The first time you enter the loop, `line` is the first non comment line. You're skipping it by reading another line immediately. A quickfix would be to *use* `line`:

```
for line in dropwhile(is_comment, f):           
    Nat = line
    print("Nature:", Nat)

    S = f.readline()
    print("Size, S:", S)
```

A more pythonic way would be manual iteration.

```
d = dropwhile(is_comment, f)
nat = next(d)
size = next(d)
```

Comment: Ah that explains it, it works now!
Thank you very much, and thanks for the clean pythonic way :)

Answer (score 1):

Below (assuming you need all file lines)

```
with open('foo.dat') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() if l[0] != '#']
    print(lines[0])
    print(lines[1])
    for line in lines[2:]:
        fields = [f for f in line.split(' ') if len(f)]
        print(fields)
```

Comment: @Rahoul As you can see there is no reason to use `dropwhile`. Simple python logic does the job.

Comment: Indeed, if there's a simple way to do without importing modules, I'll always try to pursue that. I'll have to give the reply to @Jean-Francois Fabre though, since his answer is closer to the problem at hand, but thanks again!

Comment: As from the 3rd non-commented line, the .dat file is divided into columns. I'm trying to split them using this:
`rows = [lines.split() for lines in f.readlines() if len(lines.split()) > 1]
print("row1:", rows[0])`
But I get a "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @Rahoul I have updated the code to support your last comment,

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can extract lines which are not empty or comment (start with `#`):

```
with open('foo.dat') as f:
    no_comment_lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines() 
                        if l.strip() and not l.startswith('#')]
for l in no_comment_lines:
    print(l)
```